# Eclipse Plug-in Counting Click / Listening To Click

Tags: java, eclipse, api, plugins, eclipse-plugin

I am writing a plugin for MagicDraw an IDE based on eclipse. I want the application to close after 15 minutes of idle time to release the license.

What i first did implement a counter that will check the mouse position every 1000 ms. And each time the mouse location remained the same i decreased the counter. And when the counter reached 0 i closed the application. And each time to position changed i reset the counter.

The problem here was that if the application is open and the user is just moving his mouse around in a different window he is not categorized as idle.

My second approach was to count the number of clicks. But the problem that i am facing is i am not getting how to add a listener to the full IDE window.

Here is what i have so far.

```
package myplugin;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
public class CheckAct implements MouseListener{
    private int timeleft;
    private int permtime ;
    public CheckAct(int initialTime){
        this.setPermtime(initialTime);
        this.setTimeleft(initialTime) ;
        //Missing Addlistener Code
    }
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        this.resetTime();
    }   
}
```

where i have the `//missing addlistenercode` is where i believe i should add the listener to the full eclipse window to be able to use the mouseClicked event.

But how do i do that ?

Please note i only showed relevant code.

Answer (score 1):

Cause you are using eclipse you can use SWT to capure mouse events. The easies way is to register a Listener on the Display-Instance to get all events of all application windows.

```
PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getDisplay().addListener(SWT.MouseDown, new Listener() {
  @Override
  public void handleEvent(Event event) {
  //TODO
  }
});
```

Comment: @Marwan Doumit does this answer worked for you? If yes please accept it!

Comment: This is not quite what i was looking for.